# (Withdrawn) C++ fstream inserts NULL byte when closing file after reopening

Tags: c++, fstream

Note: I couldn't reproduce this bug with another file so it must be some side effect. Please ignore for now!

Compiler: Microsoft C++ 2010, Platform: Windows 8

I'm using a std::fstream for opening an existing text file to append data at the end of the file. This should be simple:

```
ofstream out;
out.open(fname);
out << "Hello";
out.close();
out.open(fname, ios::in | ios::out | ios::ate);
out << "World";
out.close();
```

The data is being appended at the end, but the first new char is automatically replaced by a NULL byte:

```
Hello\0orld
```

This happens at the very moment when the reopened file is being closed. Everything is fine while the file is still open:

```
ofstream out;
out.open(fname);
out << "Hello";
out.close();                // -> "Hello"
out.open(fname, ios::in | ios::out | ios::ate);
out << "World";
out.flush();                // -> "HelloWorld"
out.seekp(-7, ios::cur);
out << "Test";
out.flush();                // -> "HelTestrld"
out.close();                // -> "HelTe\0torld"
```

The NULL byte is always placed at the position the write pointer had when reopening the file.

I'ver never seen this behaviour with my previous compiler. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you wanna use std::ofstream with the tag std::ios::in ?

Comment: You must if you want to append. `ios::ate` doesn't work without `ios::in`.